# IntelliJ CodeStyle Java - wrap binary expression instead of parameter

Tags: intellij-idea

In my code at work, I'm logging a lot.  The log methods that I call are similar to the println methods available in the PrintStream class.  As such, I'll use that in my examples instead of the actual code.

Here is some sample code, beautifully formatted.

```
System.err.println("There were a different number of things before (" + thingsBefore.size()
                           + ") than after (" + thingsAfter.size() + ")!");
```

However, IntelliJ wants to format it like this.  Ew!

```
System.err.println(
        "There were a different number of things before (" + thingsBefore.size() + ") than after ("
                + thingsAfter.size() + ")!");
```

Is there any way to prefer wrapping the binary expression over the wrapping of the entire parameter?

Comment: You think that your first example is beautifully formatted? It looks like arbitrary carriage returns to me. Personally, I like putting each phrase on its own line, starting with a +. Intellij supports this just fine. I think the problem here is that you want to apply something for which there is no discernible rule -- i.e. inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, the example is contrived and my comments about the beauty of the code are slightly exaggerated.  However, the carriage return is not arbitrary seeing how the I have my max line length set to 120 characters.  The overall point is that IntelliJ wanted to wrap the parameter to the next line when, in my preference, it would have been better to only wrap the binary expression since it had to wrap it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't. The method '(' will wrap the line. Since long binary expressions are usually Strings, you can reformulate it with [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). This makes it more readable and the text can also be kept in a [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html):

```
    System.err.println(String.format(
            "There were a different number of things before (%d) than after (%d)!",
            thingsBefore.size(), thingsAfter.size()));
```

I also prefer alignment when multiline.

[image: Method call arguments: Align when multiline]

[image: Binary expressions: Align when multiline]

Comment: With slf4j you can access the same string format feature without specifically using spring format. The first argument to the log statement should be the format, then you can have either a single parameter, or a collection of parameters (wrapped in curly braces). The benefit of using the slf4j method is that formatting will only happen if logging is enabled at that level, giving a slight performance boost if it isn't.

Comment: Thankfully, since the code I write is all test code, I don't need to worry about localization.  +1 for the work around though.  I'll accept eventually if no one else is able to come up with a better solution.